# Circle appeared on cursor, not about selection mode, blender 3.1.0

Tags: selection-tools

Has anyone encountered this yet? It's really bothering me now, I have to hit esc or RMB every single time before selecting anything. The circle keeps coming back after every single selection. I can't click on any other button with this circle around my cursor, and the radius of the circle changes when I scroll MMB.

[image]

And I don't think it's a selection mode problem. Since I can't even switch selection mode by hitting "W" as long as this circle is there.

If I'm in circle selection, then there will be two circles with my cursor.

[image]

Here's the screen recording of this problem after I re-download and relaunch an older version, whereas the problem is still there. The cursor change back to normal only after I hit esc, but soon it changes back to this weird situation.

[image]

Comment: The keyboard shortcut for Circle Select is C. Are you, or a random piece of debris or keyboard damage accidentally holding down or pressing the C key?

Comment: Try pressing 'W' a couple of times with the L/H selection icon hilighted. That should cycle through the selection modes in Edit mode and the icon should change on each keypress.

Comment: @Onyx Well, I think there's a problem with my C key, but I think it is not stuck instead I need to press it down several times to make it work. A common problem with a macbook's keyboard.

Comment: @JohnEason Thx for the reply, I can't use W cycle through selection modes, unless I  hit esc to get rid of this weird circle. And the circle is there all the time no matter what selection mode I'm in. If I'm circle selection, then there will be two circles with my cursor.

Comment: did you try downloading the newest version? does this happen in all Blender versions?

Comment: @Chris I just downloaded an older version of blender and relaunched it, and this problem is still there, have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: That’s really weird

Comment: Must be a keyboard problem as you guessed in that case. :^(

Comment: try disconnecting the keyboard and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @JohnEason But my C key is working properly for when I'm typing, very strange.

Comment: Yeah. I don't know anything about Macs, but it sounds as if something else in the operating system must be interfering if you're still getting the problem with a different Blender version.

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted my macbook and problem got solved.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem just occurred to me. I found the solution [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/blender-2-80-cursor-has-turned-into-a-circle-and-i-cant-get-rid-of-it/1168883): I had accidentally turned on "circle select" mode, presumably by accidentally pressing the <kbd>w</kbd> key. The solution is to press <kbd>w</kbd> again to turn it off.